# Ler e escrever ficheiro xlsm em php

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-excel, macro

Tenho um problema em mão bastante grande que é o seguinte: tenho um ficheiro xlsm com macros para ler, escrever e, por fim, fazer o download.

É um ficheiro com 4 MB com formatações e imagens incorporadas.

Tenho usado o PHPExcel só que não tenho conseguido ler o ficheiro por completo porque dá me o seguinte erro: "Out of memory".

O objetivo não é ler e escrever todas as folhas do ficheiro. Não preciso de mexer em macros nem nada.

Sabem qual a melhor API ou melhor maneira de poder ler e escrever esse tipo de ficheiro?

Uso laravel e uso um servidor linux.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema?

Comment: Não. Resolvi o meu problema de maneira diferente. Tive de desenvolver uma mini aplicação em Java para poder preencher as células do ficheiro xlsm.

Answer (score 3):

Gerar arquivos com `PHPExcel` ou até mesmo coisas simples podem causar o uso excessivo de memória, isto pode ser causado pela biblioteca ou pode ser causado pela maneira que você escreveu os códigos ou o arquivo no `input` pode ser muito grande.

Como loops *"mal feitos"*, não setar `NULL` em referencias que não irá usar, é algo muito longo pra discutir.

Vamos pras solução mais rápida, o erro:

```
PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 49545216)
```

Isto ocorre quando excede o limite de memória definido pelo php.ini, uma solução é editar o php.ini e reiniciar o servidor http (apache, ngnix, lighttpd, etc), abra o php.ini e procure isto `memory_limit`, então edite para:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

E reinicie o servidor http.

Se ainda o problema existir é porque por algum motivo o script esta consumindo mais de 128mb, se isto ocorrer significa que existe um problema grave no seu script, que pode ser simples ou não de resolver.

Então você talvez tenha que recorrer a soluções alternativas como aplicativos que possam ser executados como `exec` do php, ou soluções front-end como html5 (se o browser suportar) ou até mesmo não usar *xlsm* e passar a usar um novo formato que seja mais leve e portavel.

### Usando javascript

Você pode tentar fazer o uso do https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx ele suporta XLSX / XLSM / XLSB / XLS / SpreadsheetML (Excel Spreadsheet) / ODS.

Usando javascript você poderá fazer o uso da memória da máquina do cliente ao invés do servidor, isto porque a aplicação irá rodar no front-end.

Adicione isto na sua página:

```
<script src="dist/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
```

Não posso afirmar se ele tem controle sobre os macros, ou coisas do gênero, se bem que mesmo com phpexcel isto seria difícil. Então a ideia é usar o `js-xlsx` ou mudar tudo e deixar totalmente de usar arquivos do office.

Lendo um XLSM (com ajax):

```
var url = "pasta/formula_stress_test_ajax.xlsm";

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.open("GET", url, true);

oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(e) {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

  /* convert data to binary string */
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  var bstr = arr.join("");

  /* arquivo pra manipulação */
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
}

oReq.send();
```

Criando um XLSM:

```
var wopts = { bookType:'xlsm', bookSST:false, type:'binary' };

var wbout = XLSX.write(workbook,wopts);
```

Links sobre a lib

- Outros exemplos: http://sheetjs.com/demos/
- Detalhes sobre o suporte http://sheetjs.com/status/